# About $\Sigma=\{p_2\to p_1, p_3\to p_2,\, \dots\,\}$ . . .

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, contest-math, propositional-calculus

> Suppose $$\Sigma=\{p_2\to p_1, p_3\to p_2,\, \dots\,\}.$$
>
> Which of the following is true? Explain your answer.
>
> 1. For any $n$, $$\Sigma\cup\{p_n, \neg p_{n+1}\}$$ is complete and consistent.
> 2. It's not possible to complete $\Sigma$ with (a) finite sentence(s).

I think (2) is correct. Any ideas, descriptions, and excellent answers would be appreciated. (Pn is Atomic Sentence).

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Dear @Shaun, would you please correct it one times for me ?

Comment: How's that? You can see how I changed things by clicking on "edit".

Comment: it's perfect. thx

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: If you set $p_i$s to true for $i\le n$ and false for $i\ge n+1$, everything seems to be satisfied.

Comment: Dear @HenningMakholm, i edit my question, would you please submit as a solution?

Comment: Dear @MauroALLEGRANZA, would you please submit as a question?

Comment: @MichleJordan: It's not a full solution -- I'm not saying anything about completeness.

Comment: @Mauro: Whether $\Sigma$ is consistent does not depend on any valuation for the $p_i$s. Theories are either consistent or not; they are not consistent (or not) under particular interpretations.

Comment: Sorry ... I'm not able to understand the questions. I'm not able to understand what "complete" means in this context and I'm assuming - but I'm not sure is the correct assumption - that to be *consistent* for a set of propositional formulae is to be satisfied by some valuation $v$ of the propositional variables.

Comment: @Mauro: I'm understanding it as the same kind of "complete" as in Gödel's incompleteness theorem -- that is, $\Sigma$ is complete iff for every wff $\varphi$ (in the language in question) either $\Sigma\vdash \varphi$ or $\Sigma\vdash\neg\varphi$. For the propositional calculus, it is obviously sufficient to show this in the case where $\varphi$ is a propositional variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will show that 1 is true and therefore 2 is false. Note that since $\Sigma=\{p_2\to p_1, p_3\to p_2,\, \dots\,\}$, we have that $\Sigma\equiv\{\neg p_1\to \neg p_2, \neg p_2\to \neg  p_3,\, \dots\,\}$. In particular, we have $\Sigma \equiv \bigcup_{1 \leq n<\omega}\{\neg p_n \to \neg p_{n+1}\}$.

(1) Claim: for all $n<\omega$ such that $\Sigma \cup \{p_n, \neg p_{n+1}\}$ is consistent and complete.

Proof: Let $n\geq 1$. We are considering $\Sigma \cup \{p_n, \neg p_{n+1}\}$ Since $\Sigma \equiv \{\neg p_1\to \neg p_2, \neg p_2\to \neg  p_3,\, \dots\,\}$, we know that, as consequence, $\Sigma \models \{\neg p_m\}$ for $m\geq n+1$. $\Sigma \models p_n$ by assumption. Note that by the definition of $\Sigma$, $\Sigma \models p_s$ for $s\leq n$. Therefore, since $\Sigma$ makes a judgement on every atomic sentence, $\Sigma$ is complete.

It should be pretty obvious that $\Sigma$ is also consistent by observing the fact that every finite set of axioms is clearly consistent, and therefore, by the compactness theorem, $\Sigma$ also is consistent.

Therefore, any pair $\{p_n,\neg p_{n+1}\}$ added to $\Sigma$ make $\Sigma$ both complete and consistent.